# Sanity - How do you prevent edits of custom studio component text?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sanity

## Context

I'm trying to customize the style of a custom quote annotation in Sanity Studio using a custom annotation component, showing one of the annotation's properties inside of it (the author of the quote). The quote text is the annotated element and the quote author is a property defined inside the annotation.

## Problem

It's possible to start editing the quote author text as if it was normal block text, which throws errors and eventually crashes the Studio, because the quote author is not directly inside the block, but rather a property of the annotation being shown in the custom component.

This is the custom quote schema definition:

```js
const richTextQuote = defineField({
  type: "object",
  name: "quote",
  title: "Quote",
  icon: () => "❞",
  fields: [
    {
      type: "string",
      name: "author",
      title: "Author",
    },
  ],
  components: {
    annotation: RichTextQuote,
  },
});
```

How I use it inside a type:

```js
const richText = defineType({
  name: "richText",
  type: "array",
  of: [
    defineArrayMember({
      type: "block",
      marks: {
        annotations: [
          richTextQuote,
        ],
      },
    }),
  ],
});
```

This is the custom annotation component to show in the block (RichTextQuote):

```js
const RichTextQuote = (props: BlockAnnotationProps) => {
  let author = "Unknown Author";
  if ("author" in props.value && typeof props.value.author === "string") {
    author = props.value.author;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {props.renderDefault(props)}
      <div>
        <p>- {author}</p> {/* This should not be editable in the block, but it actually is */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

## Expected

I want to show the quote author (annotation property) inside the block preview, but the user is not supposed to be able to edit that text. The quote author should only be editable through the annotation's "author" property (by clicking on the annotated text and pressing "Edit")